# Getting extra space out side card component in ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am displaying movie cards by looping on data. I used a grid container and I didn't give any gap-x in the grid still I am getting extra space at the right side of the card after that center card element by using flex and but still getting extra space on both sides of the card. please help me. thank you.

Problem Image:
[image]

Card Component:

```
      <div className="flex justify-center">
    <div className="bg-theme-blue w-movie-card h-min rounded-movie-card shadow-movie-card flex-shrink-0">
      <img
        className="w-full"
        src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780${posterImg}`}
        alt="img-poster"
      />
      <div className="flex p-2 justify-center items-center">
        <div className="text-theme-white font-semibold w-9/12">{title}</div>
        <div
          className={`font-semibold p-2 bg-theme-dark-blue ${setTagColor(
            voteAverage
          )}`}
        >
          {Math.round(voteAverage * 10) / 10}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

GridContainer:

```
    <div className={"grid lg:grid-cols-5 md:grid-cols-3 grid-cols-2 gap-y-3 " + className}>
  {children}
</div>
```

Display Data inside the container:

```
    <GridContainer>
  {movies.map((movie) => {
    return <MovieCard {...movie}/>;
  })}
</GridContainer>
```

Comment: It's because div.card is not using 100% width and the card is aligned center using justify-content so space is showing on both side. Either make card's width 100% or use gap property in parent div

Answer (score 0):

Try `min-width:100%`

```
  <div className="flex justify-center" style="min-width:100%">
</div>
```

Comment: No not working any other solution? Thank you.

Comment: Then try min-width:100% on div

 <div className={"grid lg:grid-cols-5 md:grid-cols-3 grid-cols-2 gap-y-3 " + className} style="min-width:100%">
  {children}
</div>